Domain and Subdomain Path on Hostinger for Laravel app
I followed a guide by The Codeholic on YouTube explaining how to deploy a Laravel app on Hostinger. This included removing the default public_html folder, cloning the project, and pointing the public_html to the public folder of Laravel.
To ensure the project runs correctly, I removed the public/build folder from .gitignore, ran npm run prod locally, and then pushed the changes.
Now, the project is functioning correctly, and it is located at this path:
/home/u778081280/domains/mydomain.com
My question is:
Is this path correct?
If I create a subdomain, it will be located here:
/home/u778081280/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/test
So, within the public folder of the main project, is this placement correct? I attempted to clone the project here to manage a test branch of it, but it did not work (403). What am I doing wrong?
What is the correct path? Should the subdomain be located here instead?
Tried to change the .htaccess, or create the subdomain folder, with terminal in this path:
/home/u778081280/domains/test.mydomain.com
but i get a 500

With default Hostinger settings; adding a subdomain through hPanel will show a default directory at ~/home/{userNumber}/domains/{yourDomainName}/public_html/{subdomain}.
Your first path mentioned is correct where /test is inside of your main site's /public_html.
The 403 problem means that what you are asking the server for is forbidden, but the good thing is it understood what you were asking for. In your .env set APP_DEBUG=true and load the site again, it should hopefully provide more reason as to why the error was provided.
